# How to Clear Cache of Image Without Renaming the File with PHP?

Tags: php, regex, image

I have a function on my site that allows the user to rotate an image and allow that images to be saved rotated. When it saves the image is saves overtop the old image and the new rotated image now has the same filename as the old, unrotated one.

The problem is with this is on the frontend it doesn't always show the new rotated image because of caching of the old image.

So what I am trying to figure out is how to save a new rotated image with the same filename as the old image, but have the cache clear for that image, so you don't see the old image and that I do not need to change the filename.

Comment: Are you sending the image data via PHP or is it being served up as an actual image file from the web server?

Comment: you can just hang a random string at the end of your filename like `<img ... src="your.png?<?= rand(); ?>">`

Comment: @wayneOS Will that effect where I have the image displayed on the front end because the filepath isn't the same with the random number added to the end?

Comment: it doesnt change the path. the browser just think its a different image and loads it from your server instead of the cache

Comment: @JustinPearce So the steps for this is, user can upload an image in the admin section of the site, when that image is uploaded 3 sizes of that image are then created. The user can then go and edit that image by rotating it. Which would then save over the old images and be replaced by the rotated version of that image with the same filename. Not sure if that answers your question, but that is the process of what is done.